# Why does trying to use "mdir" give me "Can't open /dev/fd0: No such file or directory"?

Tags: linux, mount

Every time I try to use the "mdir" command on Ubuntu 9.10, I get this message:

```
Can't open /dev/fd0: No such file or directory
Cannot initialize 'A:'
```

Any idea what it means, and how to fix it?

Edit:
I am trying to mount a directory, as in [these instructions](https://answers.launchpad.net/bzr/+question/82628) (see Klaus Rennecke's answer).

> To sum it up into commands:
>
> Prequesites: sudo apt-get install fuse-utils sshfs
>
> Mount dir: mdir ~/sftp.my-site.org
>
> Mounting: sshfs sftp-username@sftp.my-site.org: ~/sftp.my-site.org -o idmap=user,workaround=rename
>
> Run update: cd ~/sftp.my-site.org; bzr update

Comment: Thanks, your post on Launchpad answered my question. Post it here too, so I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: i posted it here before i posted to launchpad -- check the update at the top of the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: Your instructions have a typo; it's telling you to *make* a directory, so you should run **mkdir** instead of **mdir**.

"mdir" is an old tool for accessing DOS-formatted floppy disks without mounting the floppy.  You probably don't want that.  (It's part of the **mtools** package, which you are probably safe in uninstalling.)

Are you trying to

- make a directory?  Use **mkdir**
- remove a directory?  Use **rmdir**
- move a directory?  Use **mv**

Comment: I edited the question to address this.